# d3.timeScale() X axis doesn't display years

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm making the X axis display years. However it doesn't work and my cx values are 0. My guess is something wrong with  `d3.timeFormat` parsing years values.

```
//d3.format year as yyyy
let dateFormat = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

//Define x and y scale range
let xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, width])

//Define x and y axis
let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(d =>
        dateFormat(d))

xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, d => 
        dateFormat(d.year)
        ))

let circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle");

circles
        .attr("cx", d =>
            xScale(dateFormat(+d.year)))
        .attr("cy", d =>
            yScale(d.emissions))
        .attr("r", 4)
        .style("fill", "blue")
```

Current output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/edgarkiljak/pen/MzwNQB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As been mentioned before JSON data already returns years as years (as numbers). No parsing required. But `d3.format` required for `tickFormat`.

1.`xScale.domain` becomes:

```
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, d => 
    d.year
    ))
```

2.`cx`:

```
.attr("cx", d =>
            xScale(d.year))
```

2.`tickFormat` therefore:

```
.tickFormat(d3.format(""))
```

Answer (score 2):

[d3.timeParse](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#timeParse) is what you're looking for.

As the `data` consists just the `year` as numbers, you have to parse it to full dates using `d3.timeParse`. Here's how:

1. Define a parser: `let parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y")`
2. Parse the data based on the above:

   ```
   data.forEach(function (d) {
     d.year = parseDate(d.year);
   });
   ```
3. And the `tickFormat` would change to: `.tickFormat(d => d.getFullYear())` ([Date.getFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)) as you're trying to just print the years.

   Here's a fork of your codepen: 
   https://codepen.io/shashank2104/pen/MzaoZp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the type of your `data.year` is a javascript `date` data type.  Add the `for` loop shown below...

```
//Fetch data using promises
d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/122bwe").then(data => {
    console.log(data);

// ADD THIS after the line above!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    data[i].year = new Date(data[i].year, 1, 1);
```

Comment: talk about make-work...the JSON contains a year, so your proposal is to convert it to a Date, so that the dateFormat function can then convert it back to a year again and pass it to d3. What a load of wasted effort. Just not using the dateFormat function will solve the problem much more simply.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data (from the CodePen) already returns years as years i.e. `1996`...you don't need to format them. And anyway your dateFormat function expects a full date, it can't deal with just a year.

Just remove the `dateFormat` function and all references to it, and you will get the result you expected.

Here's an updated, working codePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQjzam

Comment: However x axis still doesn't display years.

Comment: check the codePen again, I missed a reference to dateFormat. It looks like there a couple of other presentational issues, I'm not a d3 expert, but I'm sure you can resolve them now you've got the data source sorted out.